# -match fails when checking if a string contains a path

Tags: string, powershell, path, escaping

I have a list of strings, and need to check each item to see if it contains some string `$path`, where the string should contain a unc path and `$path` is also a unc path.

For example:

```
"RW \\test" -match "\\test"
```

returns `True`, as `\\test` is contained in `RW \\test`. Great.

So why does this return `False` ? :

```
"RW \\test\te" -match "\\test\te"
```

At first I though maybe the single backslash is somehow acting as an escape character (even though in PowerShell that should be `)

So I tried

```
"RW \\test\\te" -match "\\test\\te"
```

But this also returns `False` ....

Why?

Comment: `"RW \\test\\te" -match "\\\\test\\\\te"`

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for your comment. So the second string (the comparer) needs to have the \s escaped with a \\?

Comment: `[Regex]::Escape('\\test\\te')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape both of the backslashes with backslashes in your regular expression on the right-hand side of the `-match` operator.

```
PS /> "RW \\test\te" -match "\\\\test\\te"
True
```

Here's what the result looks like:

```
PS /> $matches[0]
\\test\te
```

You could also expand on this to use named captures in regular expressions. Named captures just give friendly names to individual captures inside of a regular expression, making them more easily referenced as a property on the `$matches` variable, instead of a numeric index.

```
PS /> "RW \\test\te" -match "(?<UNCPath>\\\\test\\te)"
True
PS /> $matches.UNCPath
\\test\te
```

Keep in mind that the backtick character is used to escape certain special characters in PowerShell double-quoted strings. However, in the case of the `-match` operator, you're invoking the .NET regular expression engine. In the .NET regex engine, the backslash is used to escape special characters in the regex context. Hence, in this example, the backtick escape character isn't applicable.

*Also*, make sure that you are **not** escaping special characters in your source string, on the left-hand side of the `-match` operator. The reason that your final example doesn't match, is because you added a second `\`, but only escaped a single `\` in the regex on the right-hand side of the `-match` operator.

Comment: @Bassie Happy to be of service. :) Regex can be messy when you're new to it! I've been there before. Hope this helps you learn from the experience.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Trevor Sullivan's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49419445/45375) with a tip provided by [PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) in a comment on the question:

To **use a string as a *literal* in a regex context, pass it to `[regex]::Escape()`**:

```
PS> "RW \\test\te" -match [regex]::Escape("\\test\te")
True
```

`[regex]::Escape()` conveniently escapes all characters that have special meaning in a regex with escape character `\`, so that the string is matched as a literal:

```
PS> [regex]::Escape("\\test\te")
\\\\test\\te
```

Note how the `\` instances were each escaped with `\`, effectively doubling them.

If your string does use regex constructs but also contains characters with special meaning in regexes that you want to be treated as literals, you must `\`-escape them individually:

```
PS> '***' -match '\**'  # match zero or more (*) '*' chars (\*)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat orthogonal, but for matching paths, you might find the `-like` operator easier to use. It supports *wildcards* instead of *regular expressions* so you could write your example as

```
"RW \\test\te" -like "*\\test\te"
```

Note that the leading '*' on the RHS is required- wildcard patterns are "anchored" (have to match the whole string). Regular expressions are unanchored by default and only have to match a fragment of the string.